# How to fetch data from mongodb in MERN

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, axios, fetch-api, mern

I got a problem while getting information from db to frontend in MEAN Stack.
i've try using axios plugin to fetch data, but nothing show.
this is the code:
[image: Profile-Page]

and this is my data in mongodb:
[image: mongodb]

how can i show the information to this part (ex: for username)?

```
<div className="user-details">
   <tr>
     <th>Username: </th>
     <th></th>
   </tr>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you tried it with postman tool to check whether your api returns the user array perfectly without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what is your problem exactly is, you set user as an array, but in render method you treat as a "text", try to iterate over each user by using map method and show each individual users information, if you have problem getting information from your API, try to set proxy in client-side package.json, to API port, and use actions in reacts ComponentDidMount lifecycle.

Comment: i've been try thi
`<tbody>
                {this.state.users.map(user =>
                  <tr>
                    <td>{user.name}</td>
                    <td>{user.email}</td>
                  </tr>
                )}
              </tbody>`
but still not showing anything

Comment: try to add catch method to axios.get(), and see if you get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below, Add header to your axios request, set 'crossDomain': true to overcome cors errorr.

```
export default class Profile extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: []
    }
  }

  conmponentDidMount(){
    axios.get('/api/account/profile',{ headers: { 'crossDomain': true, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } })
    .then(res=> {
      this.setState({ users: res.data }).then(profileState => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.users))
      }); //It sets the state asynchronously
    })
  }

  render(){
    <div>
      <div className="user-details">
        {
           this.state.users.map(user => 
             <tr>
               <td>Username: </td>
               <td>{user.name}</td>
             </tr>
           )
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks,
actually i just used `this.state.user.name` without maping to show from database

```
<strong>Name:</strong>{this.state.user.name}<br/>
```

and in api i get the user id in url to get current user/active user from session.

```
axios.get('/api/account/profile/info?id=' +id)
  .then(res => {
     this.setState({ user: res.data.user });
 })
```